# Generalization of Alternating Harmonic Series

Tags: integration, summation

Consider the following sum for positive integers $a$ and $b$

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{an + b}. $$

What is the closed form of this sum? Solutions, partial progress, and suggestions appreciated.

Note: The original problem asks for $a = 8, b = 3$, though we haven't solved this case yet.

Things my friends and I tried: For the case $a = 8, b = 3$, it is equivalent to $\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1 + x^8} \, dx$, not much progress here. Next, we tried writing $f(x) = \sum \frac{x^n}{an+b}$ or $f(x) = \sum \frac{\cos(nx)}{an + b}$ and writing differential equations.

Comment: What if $a=1$, $b$ - integer. The best we can do is to subtract $b$ members from full series

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can evaluate the integral by using complex numbers.  I seem to remember working this out for integer $a$ and $b$ years ago.  I don't recall whether I got a closed-form formula, or just a method for handling specific cases.  The denominator splits into linear factors, and you use partial fractions.  You may have to be careful about which branch of the logarithm you're on.  I remember considering this, but not what I decided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{a\,n + b}=\frac 1 a\,\Phi \left(-1,1,\frac{b}{a}\right)$$ where appears the [Lerch transcendent function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

For $a=8$ and $b=3$, the result expresses in terms of the digamma function; it is
$$\frac{1}{16} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{11}{16}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)\right)\approx 0.273898$$  For 
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1 + x^8} \, dx$$ $$I==\frac{1}{8} \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \left(\pi -2 \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right) \left(\pi -2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: Is it  a closet form? I think it's relabling of the above series

Comment: @Mr.Newman. I agree with you : it is not a closed form but it corresponds to a well known special function.

Answer (score 1):

The sum, in general, can be written as a difference of digamma values at rational arguments:
\begin{align}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{an+b}&=\sum_{n\ge0}\bigg(\frac1{2an+b}-\frac1{a(2n+1)+b}\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\bigg(\frac1{2an+b}-\frac1{2an}+\frac1{2an}-\frac1{2an+a+b}\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=\frac1{2a}\sum_{n\ge0}\bigg(\frac1{n+b/(2a)}-\frac1n-\frac1{n+1/2+b/(2a)}+\frac1n\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=\frac1{2a}\Big[\gamma+\psi\Big(\frac32+\frac b{2a}\Big)-\gamma-\psi\Big(1+\frac b{2a}\Big)\Big]
\end{align}and [Gauss's digamma theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075565/gauss-digamma-theorem-proof) provides the formula to evaluate them (apart from possible trig simplifications, it doesn't get any cleaner).